# MSP430G2231 reading 16-bit i2c response

Tags: c, microcontroller, sensors, i2c, msp430

I'm writing a program that reads temperatures from a couple [TMP117](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmp117.pdf) sensors.

4x Adafruit TMP117 sensor boards to be exact, with each having a different ADDR pin configuration to give them different i2c slave addresses.

For i2c I'm using the [MSP430 USI i2c](https://github.com/jwr/msp430_usi_i2c) library.
I'm having some trouble figuring out if my i2c command sequence respects the "NACK" signal bit response from the master that the TMP117s require (TMP117 datasheet fig.7-10).

My command sequence is declared as such:

```
uint16_t commands[] = {0x90, 0x00, I2C_RESTART, 0x91, I2C_READ, I2C_READ};
```

The first command (0x90) is the slave address bit-shifted by 1 from the original address of 0x48, to accomodate for the r/w bit. Same goes for the fourth command (0x91) but with the lsb set.
My buffer variable for the response:

```
uint8_t status[2];
```

And the i2c reading call as per the example provided in the i2c library readme:

```
i2c_send_sequence(commands, 6, status, LPM3_bits);
```

And waiting for response with `while(!i2c_done());`

This doesn't produce anything in the status variable even after the program breaks from the **i2c_done** loop. Is there something wrong with my conversion from the **i2c_send_sequence**'s ***received_data** parameter to **uint8_t** array, since I'm requesting two bytes with my payload? Or is the second **I2C_READ** in my payload missing the "NACK" bit? If so, then what would be the correct way of handling the read request and the data?

This is my first time using the TMP117 without any dedicated library, so I'm a bit lost as to what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is my logic trace of the signal:
[image: Trace]
The timebase here is 500us/div.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no NACK byte; it's just a bit. As far as I can see, the library should generate it automatically. Did you call i2c_init? Can you show a logic analyzer or oscilloscope trace of the I²C lines?

Comment: @CL. Sorry, I meant a bit. I guess i just mistyped that. I'm Calling i2c_init about 7-seconds before the first request. Right now I don't have my logic analyzer at hand, but I'll get a trace as soon as I have it back.

Comment: @CL. Sorry this took me so long. I've now added a trace of the whole transmission to my initial post. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Everything looks OK; the received bytes are 0x80 and 0x00. What do you mean with "doesn't produce anything"?

Comment: @CL. It turned out that my microcontroller needed a small delay (of about 1ms) from  i2c_init to the first i2c_send_sequence. It works fine now.